# Script not passing variable information into If, Else, While, or functions

Tags: windows-10, powershell, imagemagick

I have a script that was working before I started breaking it apart into smaller pieces. Something I noticed is as I try and use variables the information is not brought in. I have to copy paste that variable into my If, Else, While, or other functions in order for them to be used. I was told to use $script: but as far as I can tell that only allows the variable to "report out" of the function to be used later. I don't need that just to pull the info in.

Breakdown of my script thus far:

1. User drops a folder into a specific drop off folder.
2. The script detects a new file and starts to run
3. The name of the folder is noted
4. All the files are moved from their folder structure into another folder.
5. All those files are then converted to a single .pdf
6. That .pdf is moved to a "completed folder"
7. All the empty folders and files are deleted.

The script runs all this upon startup, then sits and watches for updates.

**My code:**

```
#File Locations
$rootPath = 'C:\IT\'
$inLoc = 'Convert Drop'
$prossLoc = 'Processing'
$outLoc = 'Converted PDF'

#File types to include in PDF creation.
$fileTypes = '*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tiff,tif}'

#Function Variables
$inPath  = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$inLoc"
$outPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$outLoc"
$runPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$prossLoc"
$remove1 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($inLoc + "\*")"
$remove2 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($outLoc + "\*")"

#Folder Watching Variables
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "$inPath"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

#Lone Counter
$freshStart = $null
$statusOld  = $null
$pathLoc    = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName

#Pulls the last write time of a folder to compare later.
$grabStatus = {$status = Get-Item $pathLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime } }

#Get PDF name from Folder
$grabFileName = {
    $folder = get-childitem -Path $inPath -Directory -Name
    $fileName = $folder + ".pdf"
}

#Move all nested files to single folder.
$moveFiles = {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $inPath -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $runPath
}

#Convert Nested files into single PDF
$makePDF = {
    & CD $runPath
    & magick "$fileTypes" $fileName
}

#Move final PDF
$moveCmplt = {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $pdf -File | Move-Item -Destination $outPath
}

#Delete Old files
$deleteOld = {
    Remove-Item $remove1 -Recurse -Force
    Remove-Item $remove2 -Recurse -Force
}

#Set compare status to current status then fetches new status.
$stats = {
    $statusOld = $status
    $grabStatus
    sleep 10
}

#Exicute main conversion together.
$action = {
    $grabStatus
    If ($status -eq $statusOld){
        $grabFileName
        $moveFiles
        & CD $runPath
        $grabStatus
        If ($status -eq $statusOld) {
            $makePDF
        }
        Else{
            $stats
        }
        $deleteOld
    }
    Else
    {
        $stats
    }
}

#First Time Start, Then Loop run.
While ($freshStart -eq $null) {
    If ((Get-ChildItem $inPath | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
    }
    Else {
        $action
    }
    $freshStart = "FreshStartDone!"
}

#Scan folder every 5 seconds for new content then run convert on change.
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

**UPDATED CODE**
It works on the first time run, but the loop is broken after converting everything to functions.

```
#File Locations
$rootPath = 'C:\IT\'
$inLoc = 'Convert Drop'
$prossLoc = 'Processing'
$outLoc = 'Converted PDF'

#File types to include in PDF creation.
$fileTypes = '*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tiff,tif}'

#Function Variables
$inPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$inLoc"
$outPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$outLoc"
$runPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$prossLoc"
$remove1 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($inLoc + "\*")"
$remove2 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($prossLoc + "\*")"

#Folder Watching Variables
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "$inPath"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

#Lone Vars
$freshStart = $null
$statusOld = $null
$pathLoc = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName
#$pathMagick = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe'

#Pulls the last write time of a folder to compare later.
function grabStatus
{
    & CD $runPath
    $status = Get-Item $pathLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
}

#Get PDF name from Folder
function grabFileName
{
    $folder = get-childitem -Path $inPath -Directory -Name
    $global:fileName = $folder + ".pdf"
}

#Move all nested files to single folder.
function moveFiles
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $inPath -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $runPath
}

#Convert Nested files into single PDF
function makePDF
{
    & CD $runPath
    & magick $fileTypes $global:fileName
}

#Move final PDF
function moveCmplt
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$runPath\*.pdf" -File | Move-Item -Destination $outPath
}

#Delete Old files
function deleteOld
{
    Remove-Item $remove1 -Recurse -Force
    Remove-Item $remove2 -Recurse -Force
}

#Set compare status to current status then fetches new status.
function stats
{
    $statusOld = $status
    $grabStatus
    sleep 10
}

#Exicute main conversion together.
function action
{
    grabStatus
    If ($status -eq $statusOld)
    {
        grabFileName
        moveFiles
        grabStatus
        If ($status -eq $statusOld)
        {
            makePDF
            grabStatus
            If ($status -eq $statusOld)
            {
                grabStatus
                moveCmplt
                If ($status -eq $statusOld)
                {
                    deleteOld
                }
            }
            Else { stats }
        }
        Else { stats }
    }
    Else { stats }
}

$runIt = { action }

#First Time Start, Then Loop run.
While ($freshStart -eq $null)
{
    If ((Get-ChildItem $inPath | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
    {
    }
    Else
    {
        action
    }
    $freshStart = "FreshStartDone!"
}

#Scan folder every 5 seconds for new content then run convert on change.
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $runIt
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) { sleep 5 }
```

Comment: Nice use of FileSystemWatcher! This is really cool but I can't help but think that this project would be much better as a C# or VB.NET project. You could compile it in to an EXE and run it as a windows service. It looks like you are capable of writing the code.

Comment: I don't see where things go wrong, but you can consider using global variables. In order to do that, type $Global:nameofvar. It should be global, so it will work from one function to another, etc. Note, each time you want to refer to that variable, you use $Global:nameofvar.

Comment: To me your technique of nesting script blocks in variables looks more like a sort of obfuscating code than I see a real benefit.

Comment: Tohny, I hope I didn't confuse you with those comments from your other post, but I replied back to you there too. I was talking about putting the file/folder operations into it's own function. The `$script:` prepended to a variable set within that function in the same script would make it available outside the function but so would returning a value from that function and setting that as a variable's value outside the function. In any case, I dropped a quick example pastebin on the other post for you to test for the idea I was referring to there.

Comment: Furthermore, I was suggesting to use a function (`function name{...}`) rather than a scriptblock (`$var={...}`) for the refactoring or whatever. I any event, check out the other post's comment I left you with a link.

Comment: This worked great! You have cleared up most of the confusion. It does make things quite a bit easier to use in function form. Thank you for your help on this! I'm posting an update to the script now after all the changes. One new issue cropped up after making that change that wasn't there before.

On my loop that checks to see if the folder has been updated, It use to work with the $action scriptblock, but when I changed it to function action it no longer worked. I made a new script block  $runIt = {action} but it still does not run correctly for the loop.

Comment: Don't forget that you write your commands as & command. This means you push them outside of the script scope. More information can be read in the link on HackSlash's answer.

Comment: Also, it is fine that you define functions, but a function is nothing if you don't actually call the function. Also "action" might be a reserved powershell alias.

Comment: It was the Global function! I had to write it as function global:action {} in order for it to work in my loop. I did change the name of the "action" function to "runIt" for good measure too. But that was it! Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summed up solution:**

Converted my script blocks to functions 
i.e.

```
$variable = {code}
```

to

```
function variable {code}
```

This worked for most of my script but the uninteded side affect was that my loop no longer worked. The solution for that was to convert the main function I was using to a global function.
i.e.

```
function global:functionName {code}
```

After this everything is working exactly how it should. Thank you Pimp Juice IT, LPChip, and HackSlash for all your help.

Working Script:

```
#File Locations
$rootPath = 'C:\IT\'
$inLoc    = 'Convert_Drop'
$prossLoc = 'Processing'
$outLoc   = 'Converted PDF'

#File types to include in PDF creation.
$fileTypes = '*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tiff,tif}'

#Function Variables
$inPath  = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$inLoc"
$outPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$outLoc"
$runPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$prossLoc"
$remove1 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($inLoc + "\*")"
$remove2 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($prossLoc + "\*")"

#Folder Watching Variables
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "$inPath"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

#Lone Vars
$freshStart = $null
$statusOld = $null
$pathLoc = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName

#Pulls the last write time of a folder to compare later.
function grabStatus
{
    & CD $runPath
    $status = Get-Item $pathLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
}

#Get PDF name from Folder
function grabFileName
{
    $folder = get-childitem -Path $inPath -Directory -Name
    $global:fileName = $folder + ".pdf"
}

#Move all nested files to single folder.
function moveFiles
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $inPath -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $runPath
}

#Convert Nested files into single PDF
function makePDF
{
    & CD $runPath
    & magick $fileTypes $global:fileName
}

#Move final PDF
function moveCmplt
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$runPath\*.pdf" -File | Move-Item -Destination $outPath
}

#Delete Old files
function deleteOld
{
    Remove-Item $remove1 -Recurse -Force
    Remove-Item $remove2 -Recurse -Force
}

#Set compare status to current status then fetches new status.
function stats
{
    $statusOld = $status
    $grabStatus
    sleep 10
}

#Exicute main conversion together.
function global:runIt
{
    grabStatus
    If ($status -eq $statusOld)
    {
        grabFileName
        moveFiles
        grabStatus
        If ($status -eq $statusOld)
        {
            makePDF
            grabStatus
            If ($status -eq $statusOld)
            {
                grabStatus
                moveCmplt
                If ($status -eq $statusOld)
                {
                    deleteOld
                }
            }
            Else { stats }
        }
        Else { stats }
    }
    Else { stats }
}

#$runIt = { action }

#First Time Start, Then Loop run.
While ($freshStart -eq $null)
{
    If ((Get-ChildItem $inPath | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
    {
    }
    Else
    {
        global:runIt
    }
    $freshStart = "FreshStartDone!"
}

#Scan folder every 5 seconds for new content then run convert on change.
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action { global:runIt }
while ($true) { sleep 5 }
```

Comment: Instead of making everything global you can pass arguments to the functions. For each variable that needs to be accessed inside the function an argument must be passed in. For each variable that is set and returned, you need a separate function. So you break it down by what each function returns, passing the result in to the next function until you get your final answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592531/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-powershell-script

Comment: NOTE: If this is your final answer please hit the green check mark. You get points for the answer and people will stop coming here trying to help.

Comment: Good to know! Green check mark has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

As with most programming/script languages, variables have a scope. They can share data within the main code, or function, but not cross that boundary unless you tell the script it can do so.

Although you can use global variables to set something globally, you can also work with functions if you do it well. Let me explain.

Functions can get variables from outside the script and return them to the caller of the function. Powershell does functions a bit different than most scripts, because it treats a function as an object, which allows you to do cool things.

Here is a small example of how to use a function with multiple variables:

```
function Tools
{

    param
    (   [switch]$MySwitch
    ,   [switch]$MySwitchWithReturn
    ,   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [String] $MyParameter
    )


    if( $MySwitch )
    {
        write-host "My Switch was activated"
    }

    if( $MySwitchWithReturn )
    {
        "My SwitchWithReturn was activated"
    }

    if( $MyParameter )
    {
        Write-Host "The parameter has value: " + $MyParameter
        $MyValue2 = "Another value, 2"

        #Lets return 2 different values.
        "Value with nr 1"
        $MyValue2
    }
}

Tools -MySwitch

$MyVar = Tools -MySwitchWithReturn
write-host "MyVar contains: " + $MyVar

$ReturnValues = Tools -MyParameter "test"

Write-host "The first value is: " + $ReturnValues[0]
Write-host "The second value is: " + $ReturnValues[1]
```

This returns:

> My Switch was activated
>   MyVar contains:  + My SwitchWithReturn was activated
>   The parameter has value:  + test
>   The first value is:  + Value with nr 1
>   The second value is:  + Another value, 2

To recap the above, the param section is used to allow lots of control on how parameters can be passed to a function. This is not the only way, but allows for really cool things, so it is my preferred method.

To give anything back to the section that called the function, simply print it out to console. By typing "a string" or just typing the name of a variable as shown in the MyParameter section.

Lastly, if you want to quickly do something, here's an example of working with global variables. This is useful if you want to have a settings section at the top of your script:

```
$Global:MySetting = "This string is globally available."

Write-Host "Accessing the global: " + $Global:MySetting

function MyFunction ($MyParameter)
{
    write-host "My Parameter is:" + $MyParameter
    write-host "The global string is: " + $Global:MySetting
}

MyFunction "testing"
```

This returns:

> Accessing the global:  + This string is globally available.
>   My Parameter is: + testing
>   The global string is:  + This string is globally available.

I hope this helps you. If not, please leave a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this Microsoft document about variable scope you need to declare the variable scope:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1

EXAMPLE:
To create the same variable in the script scope, use the script scope modifier:

```
$script:a = "one"
```

The "report out" scope you are talking about would be "global". That makes the variable available outside of your script.